# Dialog Feed to post on friends's wall AND own wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall, facebook-timeline

In my app http://www.facebook.com/citynumbers?sk=app_195571338990 I use a Dialog Feed to let users post on a friend's wall. It works fine, but it could be better:

1. After posting to a friend's wall nothing is posted to my own wall/timeline. Can this be done with the Dialog Feed or should I use another method?
2. I noticed when I do not type an additional text with the post, it does not appear on top of my friends page when this friend is already using the new FB Timeline (unless he or she changes some settings fro the app). Is there a way to fill in a default text with the post where it says "Write on [user]'s wall..." in the dialog? Or another workaround?

This is the url that opens the dialog:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=195571338990&link=http://apps.facebook.com/citynumbersfriends&picture=http://citynumbers.com/pics/facebook/clubbing_tn.jpg&name=Voor 2012 wens ik je: veel leuke avonden met je vrienden in de kroeg!&to=[user_id]&caption=Stuur%20ook%20een%20nieuwjaarswens%20naar%20jouw%20vrienden!&description=Powered by http://citynumbers.com&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/citynumbers?sk=app_195571338990
```

Answer (score 1):

The feed dialog posts only on the timeline of the person selected. If you want the user to make two posts, you need to use the dialog twice.

The second issue is a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/304599676247502

Comment: Thanks Igy.

I remember posting via an app and it was on both walls like this: MyUserName -> FriendsUserName "Wall post text". I guess this is not supported anymore...

I also noticed the posts are not visible on FB mobile and FB iOS. They were 2 months ago. Another bug since Timeline went live maybe?

Comment: Oh, you're referring to seeing (in your own news feed) that you wrote on a friend's wall? I don't think that story is still there, but your mutual friends will see it - this makes sense to me because I already know i wrote on their wall, the story isn't interesting to me because i already know its content